# Divide Time into Chunks using Postgres Queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I have two timings
start_time, end_time and interval and my output should be something like

Input:

- start_time: 10:00 AM
- end_time: 6:00 PM
- interval: 10 min

my output should be as follows

```
10:00 AM
10:10 AM
10:20 AM
....
5:50 PM
6:00 PM
```

using postgres queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that. Unfortunately it does not support generating a series of `time` values directly. So you need to generate a series of "number of minutes" you want to add. In order to do that, you need to calculate the number of minutes between the start and end time and use that for `generate_series()`

```
select time '10:00' + interval '1' minute * gs.minutes 
from generate_series(0, 
                     (extract(epoch from time '18:00' - time '10:00') / 60)::int,
                     10) as gs(minutes);
```

The expression `extract(epoch from time '18:00' - time '10:00') / 60` calculates the number of minutes between the start and the end time and passes that as the upper limit of values to generate (it needs to be cast to an integer to make generate_series() happy). The third parameter `10` specifies to generate number in increments of 10. This is then multiplied with an interval of 1 minute length and added to the start value.

Note that time literals written like that use the standard ISO 24 hour notation, not the AM/PM notation. But you can format your output using `to_char()` to get that if you want. But you should better format that in your application, not in SQL.

Online example: https://rextester.com/XUJ25540

---

An alternative way is to use the version of `generate_series()` that generates timestamps and cast the result to a `time` value (discarding the date part):

```
select gs.ts::time
from generate_series(current_date + time '10:00', 
                     current_date + time '18:00', 
                     interval '10' minute) as gs(ts);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/YRNAW81361

Comment: @Zack, yes that's true - but I assumed doing that with timestamps and then discarding the date part of them is even more confusing for someone who has never used `generate_series()`